# Adding a worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to add a worksheet and name it "For Export" Throwing error on the set WS line, "Method 'Add' of object 'Sheets' failed"  Thanks in advance.

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
'Add sheet named "For Export"
Set WS = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
WS.Name = "For Export"
Sheets("For Export").Select
```

Comment: which excel are u using?

Comment: Hm...does `Set ws = Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))` work?

Comment: Your code works verbatim for me.  I am using Excel 2016

Comment: I changed to set ws =Worksheet.add, and the error changed to "object required"

Comment: I'm using Excel 2016

Answer (score 1):

Try this VBA Macro:

```
 Sub Add()
Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)).Name =  "For Export"
End Sub
```